# Using Groovy JsonSlurper to parse an array of objects

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

Groovy here. I am parsing a file that contains a list of all the countries:

```
{
    "countries": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "sortname": "AF",
        "name": "Afghanistan"
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "sortname": "AL",
         "name": "Albania"
      },
      ...
    ]
}
```

I am trying to read each country into a parseable object that I can then process in my code:

```
String countriesJson = new File(classLoader.getResource('countries.json').getFile()).text
def countries = new JsonSlurper().parseText(countriesJson)

countries.each { country ->
    String sortname = country.sortname
    String name = country.name

    // do something with all this info and then move on to the next country
}
```

When I run this code I get `MissingPropertyException`s:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sortname for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
        ...rest of stacktrace omitted for brevity
```

**What can I do to fix this so that I can parse the array JSON objects into my `sortname` and `name` variables?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your json wrapped in `{ ... }` so it's valid (unlike in the question), you need to get the countries object first.

so:

```
countries.countries.each { country ->
    String sortname = country.sortname
    String name = country.name

    // do something with all this info and then move on to the next country
}
```

Maybe rename the variable `countries` to something less confusing?

Comment: Sorry that was a copy-n-paste bug on my end, please see the updated JSON. Does that change your answer at all?

Comment: Cool :-)  No, you just need to grab the `countries` field from the parsed json.  Having the variable called `countries` threw me for a moment...  Maybe consider changing the variable name to `parsed` or something?